# Статус Телеграм сообщения

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

Есть телеграмм бот, который отправляет сообщение пользователю. Можно ли получить статус сообщения "Прочтен" и какими средствами? 
В приложениях есть статус доставлено(хотя скорее отправлено) и прочтено. Как отлавливать эти события?

Answer (score 1):

Техподдержка @BotSupport отвечает, что в текущей версии Bot API это не реализовано.

Answer (score 1):

Взаимодействие с ботов основано на вопросно ответной системе. В принципе не может быть такой ситуации, что нужен контроль прочтения. Потому что бот отвечает сразу же, на вашу команду. Различные отметки прочтения нужны разве что спамерам, которые собираются делать рассылки через ботов. Не забывайте что бот отправляет ответ, при каждом обращении к нему. Если пришел статус OK значит сообщение доставлено в любом случае.